# Static block link cuts part of the url

Tags: cms, url, static-block, 404-page

I have a static block in which content I have this code: `<a href="/de/sale">something</a>`
The url of the project is `dns/my_installation/...`, so my point is that when I click on the block link it will direct me to `dns/my_installation/de/sale`, but instead it gives me error 404 and the url of the page looks like this: `dns/de/sale`, so basically the `/my_installation/` part is cut off.

Any idea why would that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your url like this:

```
<a href="{{store _direct="de/sale"}}">something</a>
```

If `de` is the code of your store and you selected to include store codes in the url then the link above should be

```
<a href="{{store _direct="sale"}}">something</a>
```